# How to Identify Distinct Resources that Might Have the Same Identifier?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture, api-design

I have the following two resources that I need to be represented as two different entites (*imagine that they are actually two distinct resources, ie. Similar resources from two different data storage*):

```
// Resource 1 from Data source 1:

{
  'id' : 1,
  'foo' : 'asd',
  'bar' : 'cbd', 
  'provider' : 'data_store_1'
}

// Resource 2 from Data source 2:

// lets say 'foo' and 'bar' were patched for this entity 
// to matched the entity definition, (i.e in Data store 2, both
// 'foo' and 'bar' does not map to an existing column )
{
 'id' : 1,
 'foo' : null,   
 'bar' : null ,  
 'provider' : 'data_store_2'
}
```

Since these two entites have the same identifiers (which is `id`) it is hard to identify which is which using only the ID.

One things that I have thought of is to patch the identifier:

```
resource 1 => id: 'data_store_1_1' // URI: resource/data_store_1_1
resource 2 => id: 'data_store_2_1' // URI: resource/data_store_2_1
```

so I can now distinctly identify them. I have also, thought of hashing this values for hiding implemtation details or for cosmetic reasons

```
resource 1 => id: '6c2d2dbc992b435efd7d8e62e3637734' // resource/6c2d2dbc992b435efd7d8e62e3637734 ('data_store_1_1')
resource 2 => id: '4df3bb9d8d520f61a28972a550e6a84c' // resource/4df3bb9d8d520f61a28972a550e6a84c ('data_store_2_1')
```

#### Question

Is this an acceptable way of identifying these two resources distinctly?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that the resource you're exposing must have a unique identifier (or a composite identifier), regardless of the implementation details. While @Jose's idea is ok, it implies some changes on the DB side. However your hash idea is not workable - hashing is a one way function, so if a client will request a resource based on a hash, you'll have to hash all the items in the DB (until you find a match).

That being said, your first idea is very close. The only thing I would change is the way you're wiring up that composite identifier:

resource 1 => id: 'data_store_1_1' // URI: `resource?dataStore=1&id=1`

This way, by using URI Templates (query string), you'll get those parameters "as is" on the server side, and you could also seamlessly enforce parsing/validation (both have to be integers, for example), instead of receiving a string, splitting it by `_` and then parsing the results as integers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both the data stores are associated with a single application.
If yes, try generating a GUID from a single function for both data stores as resource ID and then the resources can be uniquely identified like :

```
URI: resource/AD24F6E6C15B4A1FA853D6F78376CC1D
```